# acquiretokenasync not working in a web app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to use the following overload :
authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(, )

This works fine with a simple console app and I am able to retrieve the token.
But when I run this from a web application, the call doesn't return and no exception is thrown. I checked in fiddler and it seems the connection closes on this call.

How to get this resolved? Is it related to HttpContext having restricted permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Its probably because of the async/await, for my code I just added await before the `graphClient.Users[FromUserEmail].SendMail(message, true)`.

This works:

```js
var sendmail = graphClient.Users[FromUserEmail].SendMail(message, true);
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        await sendmail.Request().PostAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}).Wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, we acquire the token using **authorization code grant flow** in a web application. To achieve the goal, we need to implement `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` event like below([full code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect.git)):

```
private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
{
        var code = context.Code;

        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
        string userObjectID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));

        // If you create the redirectUri this way, it will contain a trailing slash.  
        // Make sure you've registered the same exact Uri in the Azure Portal (including the slash).
        Uri uri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path));

        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, uri, credential, graphResourceId);
}
```

If you want to implement the **client credentials flow**, you can refer code below:

```
 string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";
 string clientId = "{clientId}";
 string secret = "{secret}";
 string resource = "https://graph.windows.net";

 var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secret);
 AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

 var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credential).Result.AccessToken;
```

If you still have the problem, it is helpful to share the detail code.

Comment: I tried using 2.19 version of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
With AcquireToken instead of AcquireTokenAsync. It seems to work. What could be the reason?

Comment: You may share the detailed code you were developing. If you were developing a asynchronous method, we need to make sure that the code wait for the asynchronous method to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

it's just a common mistakes that developper makes regarding asyn/await

you have just to add **async Task<>** to your method and of course the await keyword near to the call of methode that retreive the token